# Tabulate flavour names in excel and give sum of flavour amounts

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I've been looking everywhere for how to do this, I have tried vlookup and I can manually merge the data, however what I'm trying to do is take a bunch of flavour names that are aligned vertically on multiple sheets, and on a final sheet grab all of those flavours, merge them, and give me a total amount of flavouring required. I'm also trying to get this to auto update as I update the amount I need to make whatever amount of juice I'm making.

I'll try to do an example as I can't upload the sheet here.

one sheet may look like this

```
French Vanilla  20
Pineapple       16
Sweet Cream     10
Mango           8
Coconut         4
                0
Strawberry      30
NY Cheesecake   20
                0
                0
                0
                0
```

The second sheet may look like this

```
Passion Fruit    20
Mango            10
Coconut          10
Koolada          2
                 0
                 0

Blueberry Candy  10
Banana Split     6
Strawberry       12
Mango            12
                 0
                 0
```

What I'm trying to do is get the last sheet to pull all of these names and numbers put the names that match together, and add the numbers from the matching names up. I don't necesarilly need it to be alphabetized I just need it to auto update as I input different amounts on the first sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this as a separate answer as it's completely different from my first answer.

Somewhere in your workbook create a list of sheet names.  e.g. in A1 put 'Norse Temple 30ML', in A2 put 'Norse Temple 15ML', etc.  Name this range - I've named it SheetList in my example.

Create this formula:
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & SheetList & "'!B:B"),"Nicotine 100mg",INDIRECT("'" & SheetList & "'!C:C")))`

'Nicotine 100mg' can be replaced by a cell reference so you can drag down.

This method will require you to manually create a list of ingredients on your report page, but the adding up will be done for you.  It will also update as you update the figures - the VBA method would require manually executing the code.

If you want a VBA solution I can create one - just need to find the time though.

Link to where I found the solution:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/119020-sumif-multiple-sheets.html

Comment: awesome, thank you for taking the time. I'm new to using excel for anything but simple spreadsheets. I know it's extremely powerful, and now that I'm learning C++ in school I figure I should make excel do the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said if there's other sheets without data, or which columns the data appears in.  I've made the assumptions that the data is always in columns A:B and there isn't anything else in the workbook except those sheets.
This code will create a new report sheet each time - run it twice it will crash as it will try and create a second sheet called 'Report' (so delete the report sheet each time).
There may be better ways to do it, and this code could definitely be improved to suite your needs.

```
Public Sub Report()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim wrkSht_rpt As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lLastRow_rpt As Long

    'Create a new sheet to put the report on.
    Set wrkSht_rpt = Worksheets.Add
    wrkSht_rpt.Name = "Report"

    'Get the data from each sheet and paste into columns A:B on the report sheet.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lLastRow = 0
        With wrkSht
            If .Name <> wrkSht_rpt.Name Then

                'If there's no data in column A this will throw an error.
                On Error Resume Next
                lLastRow_rpt = wrkSht_rpt.Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
                lLastRow = .Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
                On Error GoTo 0

                If lLastRow > 0 Then
                    'There's data on the sheet, so copy it to the report sheet.
                    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lLastRow, 2)).Copy _
                        Destination:=wrkSht_rpt.Cells(lLastRow_rpt + 1, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next wrkSht

    lLastRow = 0
    lLastRow_rpt = 0

    With wrkSht_rpt
        'Find last row in column A on report.
        lLastRow_rpt = .Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row

        'Copy all flavours to column D.
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lLastRow_rpt, 1)).Copy _
            Destination:=.Cells(1, 4)

        'Sort the column, this will place all blanks at the bottom.
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(lLastRow_rpt, 4)), Order:=xlAscending
        .Sort.SetRange .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(lLastRow_rpt, 4))
        .Sort.Header = xlNo
        .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Sort.Apply

        'Remove duplicates and find new last row in column D.
        'The new last row is stored in a separate variable as we need to original to use
        'within the SUMIF formula.
        .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(lLastRow_rpt, 4)).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
        lLastRow = .Columns(4).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row

        'Add a formula to add everything up, then copy paste values.
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(lLastRow, 5))
            .FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=SUMIF(R1C1:R" & lLastRow_rpt & "C1,RC4,R1C2:R" & lLastRow_rpt & "C2)"
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

        .Range("A1:C1").EntireColumn.Delete
        .Columns(1).AutoFit

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I've got the Flavour names in column E and the Amount in Column F I also have data in column B. I will see if I can figure out the code to make this work. Thank you very much. I'll get back to you as soon as I know if it will do what I need or not.

Comment: Alright, I've been trying to get your code to work, this is the first time I've ever used excel VBA, I know a bit of C++ and XML and it doesn't seem to be helping here

here's a link to my workbook https://www.dropbox.com/s/kv9w1k117nvtsr9/juice%20order%20calculation.xlsm?dl=0

What I'm trying to do is take all the VG and Nic from Column B on every page and put them into one spot in a final page followed by all the flavors in Column E with the numbers next to them in Column F to kick out whatever the current totals are so I can easily do a QOH check.

Currently I'm doing it by hand